# How do I write the RetroPie img file to my SD card?

Tags: sd-card, retropie, ubuntu

I have the latest RetroPie 3.0 beta .img file, a 32Gb micro SD card with adapter which I formatted to Fat32 using GParted and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. In the CLI, I typed

```
dd  bs=4M if=~(I drag "retropie-v3.0beta2-rpi2.img" here from the desktop) of=/dev/sdb2
```

and nothing happens. I think I am doing this wrong. I successfully installed NOOBS to another SD card but that process is pretty easy. I'd like to find a Linux like app of Win32DiskImager. I am not proficient in Linux (noob). Thoughts?

Comment: If my question is unclear please add suggestions to improve it rather than down votes

Comment: *by the way:* the terminal is a **command**-line and no drag&drop-gui! -- for the future it will be better to post the exact command (and result) and then explain it...!

Answer (score 4):

well... [`dd`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dd1.html) is the software you are looking for; it comes just without a GUI! therefore (if handled right) it a is pretty powerful, simple, and quick tool.

read the page for [dd at the Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md) and/or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) for further details, and you will get a command-line like this:
`sudo dd bs=4M if=/home/"username"/Desktop/retropie-v3.0beta2-rpi2.img of=/dev/mmcblk0`

**BUT be careful:**

- `sudo` is a prefix to execute commands as administrator and can potentially harm your system! - but in this case you need it to access your hardware.
- be sure you selected the right drive for `of=` because it will be completely overwritten!

---

some additional hints:
*(not necessary! just optional, maybe too much for noobs, but sometimes nice to have...)*

- since there is no "progress-bar" you can modify your command like this:
  `dd if=image.img of=/dev/sdX & ddpid=$! ; while [ $(ps -ao pid | grep $ddpid) ]; do kill -SIGUSR1 $ddpid; sleep 1; done`
  with the `sleep 1` at the end you can set the refresh rate in seconds: for example use `sleep 3` or `sleep 10` for an update every 3 or 10 seconds...
- you can also use the downloaded .gz/.xz-file direct with a command modified like this:
  `gzip -d -c image.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sdX`
- and for sure you can also combine them (now with a .xz-compressed file):
  `xz -d -c image.img.xz | dd of=/dev/sdX & ddpid=$! ; while [ $(ps -ao pid | grep $ddpid) ]; do kill -SIGUSR1 $ddpid; sleep 1; done`

---

for any other questions please first have a look at the real good [Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/)! - maybe thats why someone has voted down your question...

Comment: When I type df -f the result shows the SD Card at /dev/sdb2.  As for the drag and drop idea, I have used that in my Macintosh "Terminal/CLI"  Thanks I'll try your method that gives progress output.

Comment: *well... with some terminal-emulators d&d will work (maybe also useful), with some others not.* -- i guess you mean with `df -h` you get **/dev/sdb2** for your sd-card, so you have to take **/dev/sdb** for the `dd`-command!

Answer (score 1):

If the SD card is really on /dev/sdb you need to ditch 2, so the command should be:

```
dd bs=4M if=~(I drag "retropie-v3.0beta2-rpi2.img" here from the desktop) of=/dev/sdb
```